# Mimicking collection changes in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app. My app has the following JSON array defined on the scope when the controller is initialized:

```
$scope.orders= [
  { isSelected:false, quantity:0, price:1.33, name:'', description:'' },
  { isSelected:false, quantity:0, price:2.54, name:'', description:'' }
];

...

var addOrder = function() {
  $scope.orders.push({ isSelected:false, quantity:0, price:getPrice(), name:getName(), description:getDescription() });
};
```

I'm displaying the orders like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <div>
      <h2>{{order.name}}</h2>
      <p>{{order.description}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Whenever addOrder gets called, a object gets added to the order collection. However, that change doesn't get reflected in the UI. How do I get the change to reflect in the UI?

Thanks

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply()` within `addOrder` - depends how you are calling the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.$apply()` is required to update the scope. When you use Angular THINGS like directive, `ng-*` events, `$timeout`, `$http`, etc they come pre-wrapped with this function. When you work outside of Angular's world you'll need to start telling it when you update the scope.

Here's a good rundown on it all: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Be careful about simply sticking it within generic functions - you'll run into problems (calling $apply within $apply) if they are called by Angular THINGS as well as vanilla JS events. Associate the `$apply()` with what requires it:

```
.directive( 'myDir', [ function() {
    return {
        link: function( scope ) {

            ( scope.myFunc = function() {

                // scope.$apply(); would cause error
            })();

            angular.element( window ).bind( 'resize', function(){ scope.$apply( scope.myFunc )});
        }
    }
}]);
```